# Omitted words in a sentence

Tags: adverbs, relative-pronouns

Here is an excerpt from Steve Job's speech:

> On the back cover of their final issue was a  photograph of an early morning country road, the kind __ you might find yourself walking along if you wanted to see the world.

I'm just wondering what words could be possibly omitted between "the kind" and "you might find..." 
Is that a relative adverb, "where"? or a relative pronoun "which/that"?
- the kind of road where you might find yourself walking along? OR
- the kind of road that/which you might find yourself walking along?

I know that the omitted words are not necessary to understand the sentence, but it's just out of curiosity...

Comment: That or which. Notice the stranded preposition *along*.

Comment: The omission of the relative pronoun and "that" seems ordinary.  The omission of "of road" seems more interesting -- or was it "of a road"? or "of a country road"? or "of an early morning country road"?  And where is the antecedent for the deletion?

Comment: I'm not sure about the omission of "of (a)road" part... I was just thinking that it could be "kind of a road" or kind of a photograph." If we put "of a road which" in brackets, is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: No, use of brackets is incorrect.

Comment: in American we call those parentheses. And as Greg Lee pointed out, usage of them is incorrect. Ellipsis . . .  would have been better.

Comment: incidentally, it would be 'the kind of road which'